# JS: Redirecting after 303 See Other

Tags: javascript, http, post, get

**Background**

I have a server and a web client.

At a certain point, the client sends the server a POST request, and the server responds with 303 See Other, with another URL.

Then, the client sends a GET request with that address, and receives the corresponding HTML file.

**The Problem**

What I would expect is that the address at the top of the browser change, and the HTML shows up, but this doesn't happen. The HTML file is received correctly but isn't displayed.

**The Code**

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(this.status);
        // Receives 303 See Other
        // Sends an appropriate GET
        // Receives HTML file
        // Does nothing with it
    }
};
xhttp.open('POST', '/main', true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xhttp.send("Test Data");
```

I thought that since the client automatically sent a GET on `303 See Other`, it would also load the page and everything, but maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: Been a while since I used the native `XMLHttpRequest` but I assume the html data is being returned as a string or object (as that is what ajax does. It sends data to the server and continues the code if the server sends a response without refreshing the page). It's up to you to load the html into some element like the `<body>` for example or have the server return a usable URL instead and redirect to it.

Comment: @icecub So XMLHttpRequest handles a redirection by itself but doesn't do the reloading after the GET response arrives. Huh. Do you know any other way of sending POST request that would handle this kind of stuff?

Comment: No `XMLHttpRequest` is a callback function. It's like: Send data to the server, call me back once you are done with it so I can continue in the meantime. That way the website continues loading and doesn't freeze the browser. Hence the Asynchronous part. When the server returns data, javascript is being "called back" to the `readyState == 4` condition true part and executes the code inside the condition body. IE: Do something with the returned data. In your case it just logs it to the console. But you can do whatever you want in there.

Comment: Like for example you could do something like: IF error 303 { window.location.href = https://www.google.com }. You dont _have_ to use the returned html. Its all up to you from that point on.

Comment: @icecub Thanks for the detailed answer! Clearly I was missing on some understanding.

Comment: Sure no problem. We all had to learn at some point. Glad you got it sorted out :)